# Where do I find the parameter to pass into the findViewById in Android development

Tags: android

I have just started learning app development and I am running into the problem of not knowing what I should give the findViewById function nor where I can find it.

Answer (score 1):

In your XML layout, each `View` has an `id`. You use this `id` in your `findViewById` method.

**Example:**

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/my_textview"
   android:text="Hello world" />
```

And the corresponding code in Java to reference this `TextView`:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give it a **resource id**. `findViewById` is a method of `View` class object.

You can obtain the official reference at:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)

To start your learning:
http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

Answer (score 1):

### [findViewById(int id)](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle).

The easiest way to find element of the Android app layout is to use its ID. We could add our own IDs to almost every XML tags. To add ID we use android:id attribute.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/this_is_id_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/my_best_text" />
```

We have to set in brackets a type of View we’re looking for and then give type and name of resources:  **(view_type) findViewById(R.id.id_name).**

```
TextView newtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.this_is_id_name);
```

For more information you may visit [Here](http://android4beginners.com/2013/06/lesson-1-3-how-to-modify-textview-in-java-code-findviewbyid-settext-and-gettext-methods/).